# formal state of being

Tags: grammar, formality

I'm reading through Tae Kims grammar guide and have just got into the last section. It says that である is the formal state of being.

Can anyone tell me...why is this?

It would seem logical to me based on what I've learned that であります should
be the formal state of being. Does this mean something different?

Why is である all you need for this formal state of being?

Answer (score 1):

ます・です forms are basically for the conversation and not really for writings. I don't find です・ます formal though I find them polite.